# Jump to end of overflow-x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overflow

I've seen how this works for overflow-y, however is it possible to adapt it to overflow-x?

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);
```

I'm sure it's blatantly obvious to veterans, I've looked for over an hour and haven't found anything. I'm looking to horizontally dynamically populate a div, maybe a table with content (building an inventory system) and need it to jump to and from sections.

Comment: [.scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft), [.scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollWidth)

Comment: @PatrickEvans, if you post as an answer, I will accept as an answer. You are correct.